# Excel Weird behavior, formula cell automatically converting to value,

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet where if I enter a formula in a cell, then change one of the related values, the formula field displays the result, but is now no longer a formula, but is now a value. Below I entered a simple formula to get the rate of .04 just above it all looks good.  But when I change the above Rate from .04 to .05, the cell with the reference not only changed, but is no longer a formula or reference.  For the life of me I can't figure out what is happening.  Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: my guess is that you have a worksheet event that triggers and changes the formula to a value.

Comment: Any macro/VBA in the background?

Comment: Also what is the code behind `=GCSBaseRAte`?

Comment: Thanks Scott & Ike  No there are no triggers associated to the sheet.  All code/events are attached to control objects.  and GCSBaseRate is pointing to the cell above it.  I did get some of it to work by not using named cells in the formula, but I still have it happening